# Adding an element to a call object in R

Tags: r, regex, function, character, lm

I was wondering how I can add `& weeks == 1` to the end of `s` below?

```
s <- substitute(type == 1 & ESL == 1 & prof == T) # A `call` object

# Tried the following to add "& weeks == 1" to end of `s` without success:

 c(s, "& weeks == 1")
```

**Desired output a call object like below:**

`type == 1 & ESL == 1 & prof == T & weeks == 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without conversion to text solely at the language level using `bquote`:

```
bquote(.(s) & weeks == 1)
## type == 1 & ESL == 1 & prof == T & weeks == 1
```